# What is the difference between TestNG and Jenkins? Are both used to run Selenium test cases and two similar options?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have 3 sets of related questions:
1.Are both TestNg and Jenkins competitive tools in the industry. Do they have the same function?
2. Are both used primarily to run Selenium Test Cases?
3. Can both be used to run test cases on IDE's like Eclipse?

Comment: ?  Jenkins is an automated build server while TestNG is for writing unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Are both TestNg and Jenkins competitive tools in the industry. Do they have the same function?

No they are not. Jenkins is an Orchestrator tool that is predominantly used for Continuous Integration (As and when developer checks-in code, it must be compiled, unit tests should be run on it and if the tests pass, it should be deployed to some place) and Continuous Delivery (All of Continuous Integration + run functional tests on the deployed code and if the functional tests pass, promote the code to the next environment and eventually ship to production in an automated fashion). Jenkins cannot do this by itself. So it makes use of build tools such as `Ant/Gradle/Maven` to help it compile the code and run tests on top of it.

TestNG is a test framework, that lets developers write unit tests and also lets test engineers build their functional automation using it. Its pretty much like JUnit, except that it lets a test engineer visualise a test just as he/she would do in the real world. So they both have totally different functions.

> 2. Are both used primarily to run Selenium Test Cases?

Jenkins is agnostic to what it orchestrates. So it doesn't care whether you are using it to build selenium tests or production code. To Jenkins a build is a build. TestNG on the other hand can be used to run Selenium Tests as well. TestNG merely cares about running tests. What goes inside the test is left to the engineer who is building those tests.

> 3. Can both be used to run test cases on IDE's like Eclipse?

Jenkins is usually started and left running as a standalone server and one usually interacts with it via a Web UI. So it has got nothing to do with an IDE. TestNG can be run via the below 3 mechanisms :

- Via IDE
- Via command line
- Via build tools.